# iOS 10 Beta makes navigation bar buttons and title disappear on pushViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios10

EDIT: Please watch the video of my issue here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lzgs9mahx5mea13/AADLYfLQix7MDleDN1ER81qVa?dl=0

I have had an app live in app store which works perfectly fine on iOS 9.

However on iOS 10 (tested on device iPhone 6s with latest beta), when the cell on the master view controller is selected and the detail view is "pushed", my navigation bar's title and navigation bar buttons disappear.

Only the back button is visible.

Even if I pop back to the master by clicking back button or swiping back, they don't come back. After popping back, even the "master's" title and bar buttons are gone. I have no clue how to troubleshoot this as there are no errors.

IN my code, I am not hiding the navigation bar anywhere nor doing anything fancy with the navigation controller.

Screenshots from view hierarchy insprector:
[image]

Notice how the title and my right bar buttons on behind a few other views. the back button is at the very front. This shows that the buttons and title are not hidden, they are being covered by 3 extra views: UIVisualEffectView, _UIVisualEffectBackdropView and _UIVIsualEffectFilterView

Also in the video, you will notice that if i do a half swipe back, then cancel the swipe, the bar buttons come back. But the title doesn't.

[image]

[image]

After returning to the master, notice the master's nav bar stuff is overlaid with 2 other private class views:
[image]

I push to detail programmatically:
Relevant code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    PlaylistDetailViewController *pdvc = (PlaylistDetailViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlaylistDetailViewController"];
    pdvc.indexPath=indexPath;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pdvc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: How do you get to detail view controller? Via storyboard segue? Or by programmed instantiation of detail VC?

Comment: @pedrouan i do it programmatically. Added relevant code.

Comment: Are you sure it is only ios 10 beta specific ? I see this happens on other os versions too.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri i have tested on physical devices - an iPhone 5 running 9.3.5 and an iPhone 6s running iOS 10 Beta 7 & 8. Only iOs 10 shows this issue.

Comment: @pedrouan I added video and screenshots which demonstrate the issue. the title and buttons are not hidden, they are being overlaid with other views for some reason. Also in the video, you will notice that if i do a half swipe back, then cancel the swipe, the bar buttons come back. But the title doesn't.

Comment: @PranoyC Ok  I am going to do some investigation. If it is possible, please check or add the code of your viewDidAppear and viewDidLoad methods of both controllers master/detail (at least row, there could possibly generate issues. Generally if I inspect view, that could be origins of problem, I set them color background, red, blue, green to inspect any unwanted dynamic behaviour

Comment: Hi @PranoyC, I have the same problem with my Application. Only in iOS 10 beta the title view of navigation bar is hidden. Back button is visible. When I push a viewcontroller, the title is visible por a second and suddenly dissapear. I have tested and only occurs in iOS 10 beta. did you fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: @Paolpa no, i haven't still facing the issue. Just tested in iOS 10 GM release and same issue :(

Comment: @Paolpa actually, i just figured out a minute ago. I am using a custom GKFadeNavigationController from https://github.com/gklka/GKFadeNavigationController  Try removing it if you are using it

Comment: Hi @PranoyC finally I got to upload to iTunes Connect. How do you uploading the App to iTunes Connect? The first time I tried trough "Application Loader" and failed, but the later I tried through Xcode and this time I can to send to review.

Comment: @Paolpa as per stack overflow rules, please as new question on SO as it's unrelated to the original issue. Though for your issue, you can just research the existing questions as there are plenty about your question.

Comment: Anyone able to solve this problem? I am not using any Subclass of UINavigationBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, i just figured out a minute ago. I am using a custom `GKFadeNavigationController` from [github.com/gklka/GKFadeNavigationController](http://github.com/gklka/GKFadeNavigationController) AFter removing it, that fixes the issue.

Comment: Please check the new version (0.6). This should fix the problems, I've fixed them.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem too, and all the solutions suggested so far are either:

1. too complicated
2. doesn't work

In the end I found out that this was caused because of the updated draw cycle for UINavigationBar in iOS10.

To get around this I had to fix it with:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

It's basically triggering the navigationbar to redraw.

It's still annoying how they can just push out a new version of OS that breaks something this significant.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue but it was caused from using a custom UINavigationBar that was adding a blur view. It looks like something has changed with iOS10 that when adding a title or buttons to the navigation bar they are being added at a specific index instead of being appended to the subview stack.

I was able to overcome this issue by overriding the method `insertSubview:atIndex` and making sure the blurView was always inserted at the back of the subview stack.

Comment: yes same here, i was using GKFadeNavigationController for the custom navigation bar and had the same issue

Comment: @psychoticidiot how you made sure it is inserted at back of stack? share some code please?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue like u facing now. There are some changes i did in my code and its working. In my `viewWillAppear` write a code of navigation in `dispatch_async`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   //BACK BUTTON CALLING
   //NAVIGATION TITLE 
});
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

This will help you to set your title and back button with the help of main queue.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem applies if you are using the LTNavigationBar library (https://github.com/ltebean/LTNavigationBar)

The workaround for me was to change the code in UINavigationBar+Awesome.m:

```
Replace
[[self.subviews firstObject] insertSubview:self.overlay atIndex:0];

with
[[self.subviews firstObject] insertSubview:self.overlay atIndex:self.subviews.count -1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0 workaround for this:

Subclass UINavigationBar and override **insertSubview(_ view: UIView, at index: Int)**

```
    override func insertSubview(_ view: UIView, at index: Int) {
    if let _ = view as? UIVisualEffectView {
        super.insertSubview(view, at: 0)
    } else {
        super.insertSubview(view, at: self.subviews.count - 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solituion for my work. Create a view (viewBackground) with all the images and colors that conform the navigation bar and then y convert it in a image and use it like a background.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(viewBackground.bounds.size, viewBackground.opaque, 0.0);
[viewBackground.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[[UINavigationBar appearance]            setBackgroundImage:img forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:img forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the actual question in hand. Plus this is a terrible idea.

Comment: Why? it's work perfect. What do you implement to solve it?

Comment: because the question has nothing to do with images or changing the background image of a navigation bar which your answer is doing. It might work perfect in your particular scenario but the question is completely different.

Comment: Sorry but i have the same problem and solve it with this.